# Photoshop CC 2015 Could Not Apply the Workspace Because There is Not Enough Memory (RAM)

Tags: memory, adobe-photoshop

I really need some help here. Every time I try to render lighting effects I get the message "could not apply the workspace because there is not enough memory (RAM)".

First, this message popped up: "The 3D features requires that "Use Graphics Processor" is enabled the performance preferences (it is). Your video card must meet the minimum requirements and you may need to check that your driver is working correctly." That goes away after one time, but the lack of RAM one still persists.

Everything was working perfectly the other day and I haven't changed anything since I got the message. I restarted the computer, uninstalled/reinstalled PS CC 2015, and updated my graphics driver but obviously, nothing has worked. I have 4GB of RAM by the way and am using Windows 8.1. The graphics card is old and weak, but like I said it was doing its job a few days ago.

Please help. I feel like tearing my hair out.

Thank you!

Comment: There's not a lot to go on here, but... 4GB RAM isn't much for Photoshop. I hope you have a 64-bit OS so you can at least gain some in VM. Make sure you're not running any other apps at the same time. Check you have sufficient pagefile & scratch space. Tell us what the GPU is, so we can at least have a guess as to whether it can help out.

Comment: I do have a 64-bit OS and it doesn't matter if applications are running or not. I still get the same message. Scratch space is fine, there's more than half free. It's embarrassing and I'm looking into a new laptop, but the current GPU is an Intel Celeron 1007U @ 1.50GHz. But like I said before everything worked fine just days ago.

Comment: Was there an update to Photoshop since it last worked? You could also try making certain you have installed the latest drivers, particularly for your graphics chip.

Comment: I updated the graphics chip. The only fix I could find was to upgrade to Photoshop CC 2017.

Answer (score 0):

To add a formal answer for anyone else reading this: Please take note of the difference between Windows 10 and Windows 7/8/8.1 as far as what you are buying.

Windows 10 is a software service. You do not buy a license to what is on your disk, you buy a rolling license to the 'current' version of Windows on offer. Aside from Windows making it harder to update, this has a number of effects.

1. Windows now doesn't have to worry about compatibility too much. If something works on Windows XP SP2 and up, there are easily 25 service packs and a few thousand updates between then and now. No more do developers have to support today's Windows 10 + all the previous versions of 10 he can in case someone has bad internet and turns off updates. This results in much less bugs. At least as far as 7 most programs worked on all versions and configurations of Windows provided you had libraries like VC, but unpredictably.
2. Because the definition of Windows 10 is always the current one, Microsoft don't have to apologise to anyone when making large, possibly program breaking updates. Developers used to moan about this because it sometimes came with a need for new hardware.
3. Illegal and end of life software now will stop working randomly as these changes are made and there are no pirates/developers to create new versions. A 2015 copy of PS CC will almost definitely lack the changes made by Microsoft in the following 3 years. As piracy is on the decline anyway and security holes get detected and patched, this means the newer versions might not even be defeatable by pirates. Saved a few industries imo. This is why developers don't moan anymore about this.